# How do I calculate the Inner Soddy Centre point in cartesian coordinate form?

Tags: math, geometry

I am starting a project that involves circle packing and will be positioning variously sized discs with their centres arranged triangularly; i.e. 3 circles externally tangent to each other, forming a curvilinear triangular region between them, repeated over. It is into this region that I want to position a 'Soddy Circle' that is tangent to the other 3 circles. While I have an equation to calculate the radius of such a circle, an equation to calculate its cartesian centre seems impossible to find.

I have scoured the internet for several weeks now, and found references to Kimberling numbers - X(176) being the Inner Soddy Centre that I'm interested in (sometimes called the Equal Detour Point). My searches have taken me to Wolfram MathWorld https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EqualDetourPoint.html but I can't work out how to apply this to the calculation of cartesian coordinates.

I've stumbled across the concept of barycentric coordinates and equations to calculate them for the inner Soddy centre, but cannot then find a way to convert to (x,y) form.

StackExchange has a couple of Soddy Circle references, this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475359/center-of-soddy-circle looking particularly promising, but there seem to be key steps in the sequence of calculations that are skipped over.

Can anyone offer a solution, or flesh out the above StackExchange post for the benefits of a non-mathematician?

Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [convert Barycentric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Conversion_between_barycentric_and_Cartesian_coordinates) point `P=(L1:L2:L3)` in triangle `ABC` to Cartesian coordinates use:

```
xP = L1*xA+L2*xB+L3*xC
yP = L1*yA+L2*yB+L3*yC
```

to find the [equal detour point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_detour_point):

```
s = (a+b+c)/2;
delta = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
//barycentric coordinates
L1 = a+delta/(s-a);
L2 = b+delta/(s-b);
L3 = c+delta/(s-c);
LSum = L1+L2+L3;
L1 = L1/LSum;
L2 = L2/LSum;
L3 = L3/LSum;


//cartesian coordinates
xEDP = L1*xA+L2*xB+L3*xC;
yEDP = L1*yA+L2*yB+L3*yC;

rInnerSoddy = sqrt((xEDP-xA)^2+(yEDP-yA)^2)-rA;
```

, where `s` and `delta` are semiperimeter and area of the triangle respectively.

[image]

Lambdas in above image **are not** lengths in cartesian space.

Comment: Fantastic saastn; this is so clear to understand! I was quite close too - I'd learned that the 3 barycentric coordinates must sum to '1' but I'd missed the steps where you first sum them and them divide by them. Thank you very much.